# Очертя голову - происхождение поговорки

Tags: фразеология

Есть много определений для безумных поступков, например, когда человек бежит, не разбирая дороги. И, если "бежать, сломя голову" мы тут уже обсуждали, то вот выражение "очертя голову" - вроде бы, нет.
А что значит, "очертя"? Мне представляется что-то вроде того, как на месте преступления обводят убитого)))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У русских воинов была традиция, перед схваткой трижды очертить холодным оружием над головой круг. В частности, этой традицией кавалерист-девица Н. Дурова объясняла свой переход из улан в гусары, девушке было слишком тяжело вращать над головой массивную пику.

Очертя голову - это с такой решимостью, словно в рукапашный бой.

Answer (score 2):

Интересно, что ни Даль, ни Михельсон, ни Фасмер - в отличие от современных знатоков фразеологии - ни словечка не говорят о "древнем обычае русских воинов" очерчивать себя оружием.
Михельсон :

> Очертя голову (иноск.) — отчаянно, на погибель, рискуя головой.
>
> Ср. **Очерчивать деревья, готовя ихъ въ рубку**.
>
> Ср. Впечатлительный и страстный, я очертя голову бросался въ жизнь, отдаваясь минутному увлеченію...
>
> Григоровичъ. Литерат. восп. 7.

Даль :

> || Чертить лес, сев. подсачивать деревья, готовить к рубке, сбивая кору.

Мнение Фасмера точно такое же.
Очертить - отделить.

[image]
Очертя голову - отделив голову от принятия решения, наобум, напропалую, не подумавши.

***Дополнение***.
Вторая версия, которая на самом деле должна быть первой. Всем известен глагол *осточертеть*, в основе которого - "сто чертей". Менее известен, но тем не менее существует глагол **очертЕть**, в основе которого - враг рода человеческого - "чёрт".

> Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Золото (1892)
>   ― Кожин меня за воротами ждет, Степан Романыч… **Очертел он окончательно** и дурак дураком. Я с ним теперь отваживаюсь вторые сутки…
>
> ― Что ты, Степан Романыч: **очертел человек**, а ты разговаривать с ним.
>
> Ах, Андрошка, бить-то тебя было некому! .. ― **От бедности очертел** тогда, ― согласился Кишкин. ― Терпел-терпел и надумал…
>
> Он все время молчал и только поглядывал на Марью, точно что хотел сказать. ― **Очертел Шишка-то…** ― заговорил наконец Петр Васильич, когда остался с глазу на глаз с Марьей.
>
> М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 2 (1960)
>   Вы что, спрашиваю, **очертели**, так рано косить?
>   М. А. Шолохов. Судьба человека (1956)
>   Тут немцы сзади бьют, а тут **свои очертели**, из автоматов мне навстречу строчат.

От глагола *очертеть* прекрасно производится деепричастие *очертя*. Человек думает : "А пошло оно все к чёрту, гулять так гулять!"  См. выше пример из Григоровича (*я очертя голову бросался в жизнь*...)
Две версии взаимно друг друга дополняют : *очертя голову* - лишившись разума, безрассудно.

Comment: >Я привыкла к своим кандалам, то есть к казенным сапогам, и
теперь бегаю так же легко и неутомимо, как прежде; только на
ученье тяжелая, дубовая пика едва не отламывает мне руку,
особливо, **когда надобно вертеть ею поверх головы**: досадный
маневр!

Н. А. Дурова "Записки кавалерист-девицы"

Comment: Досадный сей маневр черчения пикой на учениях - какое имеет отношение к фразеологии и магически-мифическим ритуалам древних воинов?

Comment: А для чего, по-вашему, этот манёвр нужен?

Comment: У Гумилева можно спросить :  
>«Пики к бою, шашки вон!» — скомандовал я, и мы продолжали нестись. Немцы орали и вертели пики над головой.

Answer (score 1):

Словарь фразеологии говорит, что есть несколько  версий происхождения оборота.

1. Выражение связано с древним поверьем: чтобы оградить себя от нечистой силы и опасностей, с ней связанных, достаточно было очертить вокруг себя круг. Эта черта, заговоренная особой молитвой, приобретала магическое свойство: нечистая сила не имела власти над человеком, очерченным таким кругом. Древнерусские воины, вступая в бой, очерчивали концом меча магический круг над своей головой, охраняя себя от гибели. От этого воинского обряда и произошло выражение.
2. Выражение является результатом контаминации оборотов очертя кругом и сломя голову.
3. Поговорка родилась в поздние христианские времена и связана с обычаем креститься перед серьезной работой. Торопливые люди крестились быстро, что зрительно напоминало очерчивание троеперстием круга вокруг головы.

Я думаю, имеют место все 3 объяснения. Первое - главное. Третье - следствие первого. Известно, что христианство вобрало в себя и древние верования, и суеверия в том числе. Вместо очерчивания осеняли себя крестом, но в быстром темпе действительно получался круг.

Comment: О традиции очерчивать голову перед боем я читал ещё в мемуарах Н. А. Дуровой (начало XIX века), причём никаких крестов она при этом не вспоминала. Круг очерчивали над головой, а крестом осеняют перед собой, причём не кругом, а звездой, смешивание этих понятий, по-моему, сомнительно.

Answer (score 0):

> А для чего, по-вашему, этот манёвр нужен?

Обычная тренировка. Сначала крутитили булаву или мечи. Это было боевым прикмом. Когда они исчезли из арсеналов, стали крутить пики - самое тяжелое, что оставалось. Ну еще некоторое психологиеское оружие

Answer (score 0):

Осточертеть-к сотне чертей, слишком простенькое отношение, смысл другой, как раз связанный с кругом, корень ость+черта, ость-палка-кол, у станешь вращать над головой, оттуда и смысл - надоело.

Comment: ЧертЕть и чертИть - глаголы разного происхождения (чёрт и черта).
>Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона (оригинальная орфография)

>Осточертеть
>**Осточертѣть** (иноск.) опротивѣть (какъ сто чертей).
Ср. Брось разговоры. Что̀ ты можешь сказать человѣку, ежели ему жизнь осточертѣла?
М. Горькій. Супруги Орловы.
Ср. Осточертѣла мнѣ совсѣмъ эта пшеница своими анаѳемскими расходами.
Данилевскій. Бѣглые въ Новороссіи.

Comment: Очень интересное замечание, персонаж черта появился с русских сказок, ранее писалось слово через букву о, то есть появление слова ос то черте ть, не ранее  реформы 18 века, замена в корневой буквы проблематична.

Comment: Как писалось выражение "сто чертей" в старой орфографии,см. выше (*как сто чертей*). Слово *осточертеть* сложилось примерно в середине 19 века, раньше оно не встречалось нигде. Ещё проблемы имеются?